# What is the meaning of `-static` in `go build -ldflags`'s arguments?

Tags: go

What is the meaning of `-static` in `go build -ldflags`'s arguments?

```sh
go build -a -v -ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags \"-static -L /usr/lib -ltensorflow\" -s -w -X main.version=${IDE_DATE}-${IDE_VERSION}-${IDE_OS}-${IDE_ARCH}" -o $2 cmd/backend.go
```

Where can I find the documentatuion about `-static` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your go enviroment is using gcc compiler:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

> -static
>
> On systems that support dynamic linking, this overrides -pie and
>   prevents linking with the shared libraries. On other systems, this
>   option has no effect.